# Parsing a file that has two columns detailing a parent-child relationship of rows

Tags: r

I have spent a good deal of time looking around and cannot find a solution to my specific question. I would really appreciate any help.

I have a data.frame with 5 columns where each row details a specific taxonomic level (i.e. the superkingdom Bacteria). Each one of these levels is related to another row (and level) through a parent-child relationship. The taxon_id is a unique value (i.e. the superkingdom Bacteria has a taxon_id of 2), and is linked to other rows through the parent_id variable (i.e. the phylum Proteobacteria is nested within the superkingdom Bacteria). As a quick recap, the taxon_id is the unique value (and parent value) and the parent_id is how each child is related back to the parent. There is also an abundance variable that sums all of the abundances for all child rows, making it a cumulative sum).

Here is an example of what the data frame looks like:

```
abundance <- c(0.8157, 0.8153, 0.4947, 0.4807, 0.3444, 0.3444, 0.3444, 0.3444, 0.3444, 0.2104, 0.1466, 0.1401, 0.1299, 0.1299, 0.123, 0.1112, 0.1034, 0.1034, 0.1034, 0.1034, 0.07469, 0.07469, 0.06833, 0.06833, 0.06384, 0.06384, 0.06314, 0.06314, 0.06298, 0.06271, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.0625, 0.06184, 0.06184, 0.05218, 0.05218, 0.05218, 0.04547, 0.04547, 0.04547, 0.04532, 0.03121, 0.02122, 0.01438, 0.01438, 0.01438, 0.01438, 0.01438, 0.01411, 0.01329, 0.01329, 0.01329, 0.01329, 0.0121, 0.0121, 0.0121, 0.01116, 0.01071, 0.008966, 0.008088, 0.008067, 0.007638, 0.007638, 0.00761, 0.00761, 0.00761, 0.00761, 0.00761, 0.007381, 0.006763, 0.00676, 0.00676, 0.00676, 0.006413, 0.004669, 0.004669, 0.004669, 0.004669, 0.004669, 0.004637, 0.004637, 0.004637, 0.004637, 0.004637, 0.003418, 0.003346, 0.002479, 0.002479, 0.002479, 0.002479, 0.001818, 0.001818, 0.001818, 0.001818)
taxon_id <- c(131567, 2, 1224, 1236, 135619, 224372, 1177179, 519051, 59753, 1239, 91061, 186826, 1301, 1300, 1313, 869308, 2037, 85003, 1760, 201174, 543, 91347, 570, 573, 186802, 186801, 31979, 1485, 1491, 1221327, 85006, 85023, 33882, 1160710, 36807, 72407, 1185419, 1460422, 662, 641, 135623, 672, 1219061, 85007, 135622, 53246, 267888, 1307437, 176102, 1229202, 85025, 1817, 1206725, 37327, 1743, 31957, 85009, 1747, 1159092, 28211, 1284824, 1236101, 1716, 1653, 1883, 2062, 85011, 1160718, 114687, 81852, 38284, 1350, 1352, 525279, 1311, 198251, 54526, 82117, 198252, 314261, 90371, 59201, 28901, 590, 1218143, 525260, 862512, 204441, 41295, 191, 95605, 356, 41294, 1073, 95607)
parent_id <- c(1, 131567, 2, 1224, 1236, 135619, 519051, 59753, 224372, 2, 1239, 91061, 1300, 186826, 1301, 1313, 85003, 1760, 201174, 2, 91347, 1236, 543, 570, 186801, 1239, 186802, 31979, 1485, 1491, 2037, 85006, 85023, 36807, 33882, 573, 1460422, 72407, 641, 135623, 1236, 662, 672, 2037, 1236, 267888, 135622, 176102, 53246, 672, 85007, 85025, 37327, 1817, 31957, 85009, 2037, 1743, 1313, 1224, 573, 573, 1653, 85007, 2062, 85011, 2037, 114687, 1883, 186826, 1716, 81852, 1350, 1352, 1301, 54526, 82117, 28211, 198251, 198252, 59201, 28901, 590, 543, 90371, 38284, 38284, 28211, 204441, 41295, 191, 28211, 356, 41294, 1073)
rank <- c("no_rank", "superkingdom", "phylum", "class", "order", "family", "strain", "species", "genus", "phylum", "class", "order", "genus", "family", "species", "strain", "order", "subclass", "class", "phylum", "family", "order", "genus", "species", "order", "class", "family", "genus", "species", "strain", "suborder", "family", "genus", "strain", "species", "subspecies", "no rank", "strain", "genus", "family", "order", "species", "strain", "suborder", "order", "genus", "family", "strain", "species", "strain", "family", "genus", "strain", "species", "genus", "family", "suborder", "species", "strain", "class", "strain", "strain", "genus", "family", "genus", "family", "suborder", "strain", "species", "family", "species", "genus", "species", "strain", "species", "genus", "no rank", "no rank", "species", "strain", "strain", "subspecies", "species", "genus", "no rank", "strain", "strain", "order", "family", "genus", "species", "order", "family", "genus", "species") 
taxonomy_name <- c("cellular_organisms", "Bacteria", "Proteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Oceanospirillales", "Alcanivoracaceae", "Alcanivorax_hongdengensis_A-11-3", "Alcanivorax_hongdengensis", "Alcanivorax", "Firmicutes", "Bacilli", "Lactobacillales", "Streptococcus", "Streptococcaceae", "Streptococcus_pneumoniae", "Streptococcus_pneumoniae_SPN021198", "Actinomycetales", "Actinobacteridae", "Actinobacteria", "Actinobacteria", "Enterobacteriaceae", "Enterobacteriales", "Klebsiella", "Klebsiella_pneumoniae", "Clostridiales", "Clostridia", "Clostridiaceae", "Clostridium", "Clostridium_botulinum", "Clostridium_botulinum_CDC66177", "Micrococcineae", "Microbacteriaceae", "Microbacterium", "Microbacterium_laevaniformans_OR221", "Microbacterium_laevaniformans", "Klebsiella_pneumoniae_subsp._pneumoniae", "Klebsiella_pneumoniae_subsp._pneumoniae_ST258-K26BO", "Klebsiella_pneumoniae_subsp._pneumoniae_ST258", "Vibrio", "Vibrionaceae", "Vibrionales", "Vibrio_vulnificus", "Vibrio_vulnificus_NBRC_15645_=_ATCC_27562", "Corynebacterineae", "Alteromonadales", "Pseudoalteromonas", "Pseudoalteromonadaceae", "Pseudoalteromonas_agarivorans_S816", "Pseudoalteromonas_agarivorans", "Vibrio_vulnificus_B2", "Nocardiaceae", "Nocardia", "Nocardia_brevicatena_NBRC_12119", "Nocardia_brevicatena", "Propionibacterium", "Propionibacteriaceae", "Propionibacterineae", "Propionibacterium_acnes", "Streptococcus_pneumoniae_PNI0010", "Alphaproteobacteria", "Klebsiella_pneumoniae_VAKPC252", "Klebsiella_pneumoniae_JHCK1", "Corynebacterium", "Corynebacteriaceae", "Streptomyces", "Streptomycetaceae", "Streptomycineae", "Streptomyces_auratus_AGR0001", "Streptomyces_auratus", "Enterococcaceae", "Corynebacterium_accolens", "Enterococcus", "Enterococcus_faecium", "Enterococcus_faecium_TX1330", "Streptococcus_agalactiae", "Candidatus_Pelagibacter", "SAR11_cluster", "unclassified_Alphaproteobacteria", "Candidatus_Pelagibacter_ubique", "Candidatus_Pelagibacter_ubique_HTCC1002", "Salmonella_enterica_subsp._enterica_serovar_Typhimurium", "Salmonella_enterica_subsp._enterica", "Salmonella_enterica", "Salmonella", "Salmonella_enterica_subsp._enterica_serovar_Typhimurium_str._STm1", "Corynebacterium_accolens_ATCC_49725", "Corynebacterium_accolens_ATCC_49726", "Rhodospirillales", "Rhodospirillaceae", "Azospirillum", "Azospirillum_sp._B4", "Rhizobiales", "Bradyrhizobiaceae", "Rhodopseudomonas", "Rhodopseudomonas_sp._B29")      
mydata <- data.frame(abundance, taxon_id, parent_id, rank, taxonomy_name)
```

I would like to parse this data.frame into a different format that is more analyzable. This would look something like this:

```
Taxa <- c("cellular_organisms(no_rank)", "cellular_organisms(no_rank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)", "cellular_organisms(no_rank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)", "cellular_organisms(no_rank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)", "cellular_organisms(no_rank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)_Oceanospirillales(order)", "cellular_organisms(no_rank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)_Oceanospirillales(order)_Alcanivoracaceae(family)", "cellular_organisms(no_rank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)_Oceanospirillales(order)_Alcanivoracaceae(family)_Alcanivorax(genus)", "cellular_organisms(no_rank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)_Oceanospirillales(order)_Alcanivoracaceae(family)_Alcanivorax(genus)_Alcanivorax_hongdengensis(species)", "cellular_organisms(no_rank)_Bacteria(superkingdom)_Proteobacteria(phylum)_Gammaproteobacteria(class)_Oceanospirillales(order)_Alcanivoracaceae(family)_Alcanivorax(genus)_Alcanivorax_hongdengensis(species)_Alcanivorax_hongdengensis_A-11-3(strain)")
Proportion <- c(0, 0.0103, 0.01396, 0.00176, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3444)
OutcomeData <- data.frame(Taxa, Proportion)
```

As you can see from the original data, the abundance for Bacteria is 0.8153, but after subtracting the abundance of all of the child rows, we get a remainder of 0.0103. I would like to generate a table like this for all of the full parent-child relationships. An additional quick note on this example table, to keep it simple, I excluded a number of child samples so the math here isn't going to add back up to the previous parent sample, the data branches heavily but I wanted a cleaner example.

Comment: Is the proportion supposed to be the node's abundance minus all of the children's adundances? So a child's abundance would be subtracted from the parents and grandparent's...

Comment: @cr1msonB1ade Yes. a child's abundance would be subtracted from the parents and grandparent's and so on. And once all of the child abundances are subtracted then use the remainder as the abundance for that level's abundance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick function I drew up - it's not super well written, but it looks like it works. You should test it a little more before believing it:

```
mydata$rank<-as.character(mydata$rank)
deparsefile<-function(df){
  df$newlabel<-paste(df$rank,df$taxonomy_name)
  df$remainder<-df$abundance
  parentstodo=c(131567)
  while(length(parentstodo)>=1){
    parentstodo1<-df$taxon_id[df$parent_id %in% parentstodo]
    for(i in parentstodo){
      if(sum(df$parent_id==i)==0){
        next()
      }
      df$newlabel[df$parent_id==i]<-paste(df$newlabel[df$parent_id==i],df$newlabel[df$taxon_id==i])
      df$remainder[df$taxon_id==i]<-df$abundance[df$taxon_id==i]-sum(df$abundance[df$parent_id==i])
    }
    parentstodo<-parentstodo1
  }
  df
}

deparsefile(mydata)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I try this on the full dataset, it runs without error, but the remainder column is giving strange numbers. I am getting negative numbers and I am getting zeros where there should be numbers (like the strain level proportion in the example that should be 0.3444).

Comment: I've just manually checked a couple of the test lines - they look sensible. So for those taxa at the bottom (ie have no offspring), you want the remainder to be equal to the total? (I've just changed that) I think the negative numbers are mostly due to rounding.

Comment: Great! Im going through it too to check the numbers and the negatives due to rounding make sense to me. For the taxa at the bottom of the parent-child tree (where the taxon_id doesn't ever show up in the parent_id column), the remainder should be equal to the abundance.

Comment: Ok, so the change df$remainder<-0 to df$remainder<-df$abundance should have fixed that. send another comment if you find any other bugs